# tcsh - Command line arguments beginning with dash (-)

Tags: shell, unix, tcsh

I need to check the first command line argument to see if it's `-cleanup`.  My code is:

```
if ( $* != null ) then

if ( "X$argv[$n]" == "X-cleanup" ) then
    echo "its cleanup"
```

I first check to make sure there is at least 1 argument.  `n` is set to `1` at the beginning of the program.  When I try to run my script with `-cleanup` as an argument I get this error:

```
if: Malformed file inquiry.
```

I've tried solutions from the few forum posts I found online but I cannot figure out how to correctly handle the dash.  It's a tcsh shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script snippet worked for me:

```
set n = 1
echo $argv[$n]
if ( "$argv[$n]" == "-cleanup" ) then
    echo "its cleanup"
endif
```

When I run `tcsh ./test-cleanup.tcsh -cleanup` produces the following output:

```
-cleanup
its cleanup
```

The problematic piece of code is the following line. When `-cleanup` was unquoted, it confuses the csh interpreter as a file check.

```
if ( $* != null ) then
```

Replace it with this line:

```
if ( "$*" != "" ) then
```

Comment: I saw this problem also with a "-run" kind of argv[1]. My solution was different, but addressed the same problem. My solution was to compare this way:
  ... if ($argv[1]:q == "-run") ...